# Python3 psycopg2 test timestamp value before query

Tags: python-3.x, string, postgresql, psycopg2

With a Python string value like `2020-10-26T14:33:00`, is there a way to test if Postgresql will accept it before doing a psycopg2 query to insert in DB ?

Comment: What do you mean by _accept_ ? [mogrify](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/cursor.html#cursor.mogrify) might be what you are looking for ?

Comment: ... Usually, the column in the table and the python type should be [adaptable](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#adaptation-of-python-values-to-sql-types), then psycopg2 cares about it.

Comment: I need to valid the timestamp before trying to insert the string as a postgresql tiemstamp. If I use 26/10/2020 14:33, I have the following error : ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "26/10/2020 14:33", HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.

Comment: You might need to convert the string to a datetime object, have a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When dealing with date(time)s in Python I have found the [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) module invaluable. Using the `parse` portion of it will catch most malformed timestamp strings and will convert those that aren't into a datetime that `psycopg2` can use.:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
parse('33/9/2020')
ParserError: day is out of range for month: 33/9/2020

parse('26/10/2020 14:33')
Out[4]: datetime.datetime(2020, 10, 26, 14, 33)

import psycopg2
con = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test host=localhost user=postgres")
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("insert into dt_test values(%s, %s)", (8, parse('26/10/2020 14:33')))
con.commit()

select * from dt_test;

 id |       ts_fld        
----+---------------------
  8 | 10/26/2020 14:33:00
```